# Can we remove the idevice tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently ran across the [idevice](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idevice) tag and was wondering if we could purge that out. Currently there is only one question tagged [idevice](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idevice).
I do not think we need this tag, as it is too broad. Tags are meant to narrow down to topics, not such broad overarching tags. [ios](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) also already covers this, as do the specific tags [iphone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone) [ipad](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad) [ipod](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipod) [ipod-touch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipod-touch).
Secondly, [idevice](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idevice) is not a word. You never see Apple referring to their product lines with [idevice](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idevice).
Based on this, can we purge this tag from the system, and/or create a synonym  to [ios](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's gone (for now). Ping us if it surfaces again after the 24 hour period needed to clean it up now that no questions are using that tag.

Comment: Will do! I'll keep an eye on it

Answer (score 2):

> can we purge this tag from the system

Yes, please.

> … create a synonym to iOS?

*idevice* is not a word (agreed), so there's no need for it to be a synonym of anything.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.